# Does anyone recognize this formula to quantify the likelihood that a transformer will generate the same response twice?

Tags: natural-language-processing, transformer

The idea is simple enough. Just multiply the likelihood of filling in the blank with the same result as the original response.

$$\prod_{s:substring}^{t:string}P(t|masked(t,s))$$

Motivation:

Rather than estimating P(response|prompt) directly, it may also be useful to estimate confidence values for masked substrings. This helps identify regions of high confidence "The color of the sky is [?]." vs regions of low confidence "The color of the [?] is blue."